# Changing image from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to be able to change an image (actually doing an alert here) when I click on a checkbox with jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=who_visible]")[1].click(function() {
   alert("test");
});
```

Here is my input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="who_visible" value="1" class="btn_radio_note">
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `.click()` function on a jQuery object, this should work,

```
$("input:checkbox[name=who_visible]").click(function() {
   alert("test");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox').live('click',function() {
   alert("test");
});
```

click the link to check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yxKFX/3/